# counts the word but not the number

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, counter

lines = Counter({'you': 29, 'i': 24, 'my': 17, 'more': 13, 'one': 12, 'night': 12, 'go': 11, 'yeah': 10})

my code is this:

```
word = Counter(lines)


from collections import defaultdict

reversed_word = defaultdict(list)

for value, count in word.most_common(top_words):
    reversed_word[count].append(value)
for key in sorted(reversed_word, reverse= True):
    print("The following words appeared {} times each: {}".format(key,', '.join(sorted(reversed_word[key]))))
```

if top_words = 5

output:

The following words appeared 29 times each: you

The following words appeared 24 times each: i

The following words appeared 17 times each: my

The following words appeared 13 times each: more

The following words appeared 12 times each: night, one

but with my code i get:

The following words appeared 29 times each: you

The following words appeared 24 times each: i

The following words appeared 17 times each: my

The following words appeared 13 times each: more

The following words appeared 12 times each: night

i get the output I need if I change top_words to 6:

The following words appeared 29 times each: you

The following words appeared 24 times each: i

The following words appeared 17 times each: my

The following words appeared 13 times each: more

The following words appeared 12 times each: night, one

how do I fix this?

Comment: Please tag your questions with python so they can be seen by a larger audience.

Comment: can you please not make it as a duplicate. It is not it is a different question

Comment: you're trying to invert a mapping. I don't understand how they're different

Comment: I'm trying fix my code. I don't have a problem with mapping. The problem is with the top_words

Comment: Do this: `top5 = sorted(set(word.values()), reversed=True)[:5]`, and then get all items with these unique `top5` values.

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Too bad, no [mcve] = no help

Comment: You didn't do it right, that's why it doesn't work. The point is to get the keys corresponding to the top 5 unique values. If you've come this far, then with the hint I'd given you, you should've got it at once.

Comment: top_words = sorted(set(word.values()), reversed =True)[:top_words]

Comment: Who asked you to reassign it to `top_words`?

Comment: the top_words is an input. It changes to whatever the user asks for

Comment: I understand, but why did you reassign it? You're supposed to use the `top5` list to filter out those entries in `word` which have counts present in `top5`

Comment: but it isn't always 5 correct?

Comment: You clearly don't understand your assignment. Two different words can have the same counts, so the <number of unique top 5 counts> != 5.

Comment: how do I change that the top_words doesn't count the words itself but the count values. If that makes sense.

Comment: I'm trying to explain how without feeding the answer to you in a silver spoon. This is your assignment, and you've come this far, so please try to figure it out yourself. By the way, please don't keep creating new accounts for the purpose of getting your question answered.

Comment: I've been trying to get help but you keep marking my question as duplicate without even reading the question so no one answers.

Comment: can you please release the duplicate because it is not

Comment: I _tried_ helping you. Any more and I'd literally be spoon-feeding you the answer. So go back to your terminal and figure it out... hint: you're a couple of lines of code away. Take my `top5` hint and it'll solve your problem. Or don't, and keep blaming me for the fact that you don't want to try.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this so understanding this is hard. Thanks for the hint I'll try to figure out what it means.